# Removing credits from data view

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, layouts

I am exporting aerials with world files from data view.  I have 21 aerials I exported and each one has the credits for the service layer.  I know how to remove the credits in the layout view, but how do you do so in the data view?

I'm working in 10.2.

Comment: Edit the metadata

Answer (score 1):

Go to View -> Layout, then go to Insert -> Dynamic Text -> Service Layer Credits.

Move the credits outside the print margins, then switch back to Data View.

Comment: That works in layout view, but not in data view, which is what I'm trying to figure out.  I need to export these images with the world files, can't do that in layout view.

Comment: Switching back to Data View worked for me when going to 'File ->  Export Image', I tested with the NatGeo basemap.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working that way for me.  I have the service layer credits outside the print area in layout view and the credits are still showing up in the exports out of data view.